# How to do a PUT using RestTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I can do this for POST

```
ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(URL, animal, ResponseMessage.class);
return response.getBody();
```

But why there is no putForEntity for PUT? There is just resTemplate.put(...

How do I do it for 'PUT' request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity, ...)
```

Here is the [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map-) to the documentation of this method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [PUT](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#put-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.util.Map-) instead, reason why `putForEntity` is not available because as per standard PUT will not return a response body but 201 or 200 in most of the cases.